# Cross Domain Problem when trying to set up Arlo integration Ecommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, enhanced-ecommerce

I have got cross-domain tracking working from Site A ---- To Site B (Arlo booking system). So the sessions are being seen as one session.

I am trying to get enhance ecommerce tracking to track the value of sales but nothing is working.

Here is the code used to fire Analytics on Site 1:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-55117421-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['triex.co.nz','triex.arlo.co']);
  ga('require', 'ec');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- END ExactMetrics Universal Analytics -->
```

Here is the code on site 2 (booking site)

```
<script>

              window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
              function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
              gtag('js', new Date());

              gtag('config', 'UA-55117421-1', { 'linker': { 'domains': ['triex.co.nz','triex.arlo.co'] } });
            </script>
            <script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-55117421-1'></script>
```

I had to get in touch with them to tell them to turn on e-commerce tracking manually but it doesn't look anything is happening?

Anyone have any ideas? My code know is very limited so anything would be helpful.

Thanks

The only way I know how to check if its working is checking the ecommerce transactions in GA to see if any have pulled through but it's always blank.

Comment: That looks like minified code. Can you provide a [mcve] which isn't minified, distilled from your original source?

Comment: @NicHartley not exactly sure how to do that, here is the source code for both sites if that helps?: view-source:https://www.triex.co.nz/ view-source:https://triex.arlo.co/w/